# VBA Excel To Match 2 columns on A with 2 columns on B and return value

Tags: excel, vba, compare, match, multiple-columns

I need a VBA Excel Script To Compare columns A & B in Worksheet One Against A & B In worksheet Two If A Match Is Found Return column C from Worksheet One.

Ive can do this in excel using a formula but it is speed im after so hopefully doing via VBA would be quicker and id prefer the final output of the table to only contain values instead of formulas.

Ive done a lot of digging but cant find this piticular requirement.

Any help on this is gratefully appreciated.

This is th excel formula im currently using

{=IFERROR(INDEX(SQLData!D:D,MATCH(1,(SQLData!A:A=A2)*(SQLData!B:B=B2),0)),"0")}

Comment: This was answered by stridhan on Mr.Excel http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/975207-visual-basic-applications-excel-match-2-columns-sheet-2-columns-sheet-b-return-value.html#post4679526  Code Below

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Stridhan()

Dim c As Range, d As Range, lr As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

'rename Sheet1 and Sheet2
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))
Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A2", ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

With ws2
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 1 Then .Range("C2", "C" & lr).ClearContents
End With

For Each c In rng2
For Each d In rng1
    If c = d Then
        If c.Offset(0, 1) = d.Offset(0, 1) Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = d.Offset(0, 2).Value
            GoTo Nextone
        End If
    End If
Next d
Nextone:
Next c

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```